# Error in excel generated using OpenXML SDK when CurrentCulture is not Invariant

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, cultureinfo

### Given

I use

```
<PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.12.3" />
```

and set

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sk");
```

### When

I add a cell with decimal number

```
new Cell 
{ 
  DataType = CellValues.Number, 
  CellValue = new CellValue(1.2d) 
}
```

### Then

Invalid xlsx ids generated. I get following message when opening:
[image]

**Can I explicitly tell what culture should the document use?
I would like to avoid setting CurrentCulture globally, because it might have side effects.**

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sk");
string fileFullname =  @"c:\temp\test.xlsx";
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fileFullname, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{

    // Add a WorkbookPart to the document.
    WorkbookPart workbookpart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

    // Add a WorksheetPart to the WorkbookPart.
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
    worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());

    // Add Sheets to the Workbook.
    Sheets sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
        AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

    // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
    {
        Id = document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
        SheetId = 1,
        Name = "Sheet1"
    };
    sheets.Append(sheet);
    
    var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
    sheetData.AppendChild(new Row(new [] 
    {
       new Cell 
       { 
          DataType = CellValues.Number, 
          CellValue = new CellValue(1.2d) 
       }
    }));

    // Close the document.
    document.Save();
    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. @Liero, have you found any solution yet ?

Comment: No, I have not. I explicitelly set CurrentCulture to InvariantCulture before I write data and then revert back.